# Does ASP.NET Core's DI container assures order of services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

When I register multiple services to the DI container with the same interface and then request an `IEnumerable<IService>`, do the container guarantee that the order of registration will be the order of the collection? because this seems to be the behavior but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Example - let's say we have this interface:

```
public interface IStep
{
    void Execute();
}
```

And some implementations:

```
public class FirstStep : IStep { ... }
public class SecondStep : IStep { ... }
public class ThirdStep : IStep { ... }
...
```

And we register them to the container:

```
services.AddTransient<IStep, FirstStep>();
services.AddTransient<IStep, SecondStep>();
services.AddTransient<IStep, ThirdStep>();
```

And finally request a collection of `IStep`:

```
public class Plan
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStep> steps;

    public Plan(IEnumerable<IStep> steps)
    {
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            step.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it okay to assume that the steps will be executed according to the order of registration?
If not, what will be the best way to implement a similar pipeline behavior?

Comment: Building on response from @PeterT. If you don't find it explicitly stated in this article that they run in order of registration, that's because it is in a [different page of the same documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#extend-startup-with-startup-filters). Search for "Middleware execution order"

Comment: Personally, I would be wary of relying on this pattern.  `IEnumerable` doesn't guarantee any ordering (where the underlying type may).  If you switch to a different DI provider, this guarantee may not exist.   If you rely on the order, perhaps you need some other way of doing it rather than just 'order of registration'.

Answer (score 13):

Yes it does. The order is based on registration order and is guaranteed

Comment: Would you mind quoting and pointing to a statement in the official documentation?

Comment: @Steven I think that the behavior is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods).

Comment: In this part specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods-1

Answer (score 4):

Yes they execute in order, read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

EDIT: More specific link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#extend-startup-with-startup-filters

Thanks to @Sai Puli

Comment: Please quote the part stating what you claim because I can't find any information about that on the link you shared

Comment: If you don't find it explicitly stated in this article that they run in order of registration, that's because it is in a different page of the same documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#extend-startup-with-startup-filters.   Search for "Middleware execution order"