# Does IServiceProvider.GetServices<T>() always returns the available service implementations in the registration order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

This question specifically refers to ASP.NET core 3.1 and the built-in dependency injection container (Microsoft DI).

This [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566047/does-asp-net-cores-di-container-assures-order-of-services) confirm that the Microsoft DI container always resolves `IEnumerable<TService>` by respecting the registration order, when multiple implementation types are registered for the same service type. The order is guaranteed and this is clearly documented.

Does anyone know whether the same holds true for the [`IServiceProvider.GetServices<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetServices_System_IServiceProvider_System_Type_) method ?

If the answer to the above question is yes, does this holds true even in the following example (where two different instances of the same class are registered as implementations for the same service type) ?

```
public interface IService {}

public sealed class Foo : IService {}

var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

services.AddSingleton<IService>(foo1);
services.AddSingleton<IService>(foo2);

var implementations = serviceProvider.GetServices<IFoo>();

// is it guaranteed that implementations[0] == foo1 and implementations[1] == foo2 ???
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but I would always advice against depending on order of items in collections when you don't have full control over the order or when the method providing the collection does not explicitly guarantee a specific order (such as when specifying the sorting function as input to the method). Otherwise you're depending on an implementation detail that could change at any time.

Comment: Short answer is yes since internally `GetServices<T>`  extension method resolves `IEnumerable<T>` same as in constructors that have `IEnumerable<T>` as injected dependency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is yes since internally `GetServices*`  extension methods resolves `IEnumerable<T>` same as in constructors that have `IEnumerable<T>` as injected dependency

```
/// <summary>
/// Get an enumeration of services of type <typeparamref name="T"/> from the <see cref="IServiceProvider"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of service object to get.</typeparam>
/// <param name="provider">The <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> to retrieve the services from.</param>
/// <returns>An enumeration of services of type <typeparamref name="T"/>.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> GetServices<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    if (provider == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
    }

    return provider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<T>>();
}
/// <summary>
/// Get an enumeration of services of type <paramref name="serviceType"/> from the <see cref="IServiceProvider"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="provider">The <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> to retrieve the services from.</param>
/// <param name="serviceType">An object that specifies the type of service object to get.</param>
/// <returns>An enumeration of services of type <paramref name="serviceType"/>.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<object?> GetServices(this IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
{
    if (provider == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
    }

    if (serviceType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));
    }

    Type? genericEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);
    return (IEnumerable<object>)provider.GetRequiredService(genericEnumerable);
}
```

[Source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs,ed6b36f4cd78b748)